Is it legal for a company to tell obvious lies?
And by that I mean is it legal for a company to tell a lie that is so absurd, it is obviously a lie?
I was reading a bag of white cheddar popcorn and I noticed on the packaging it was written, "all humans have an inherent need for white cheddar, look it up, it's a fact."
Where do we draw the line between deception and jokes? Obviously all humans do not have an inherent need for white cheddar. If a fast food company says "we get all our ingredients from Mars," I suppose that's not really deception because nobody would believe that?
But this concept is a subjective topic, so when you have lies that are more believable, it begs the question where do we draw the line between deception and jokes? Are there any laws or previous rulings that make this clear?
